# How do you convert the radius decimals of a circle in Openlayers to Kilometers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unproject Radius with Openlayers with CRS:84 Projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21937/unproject-radius-with-openlayers-with-crs84-projection)

I allow a user to draw a circle in Openlayers.

I created an alert to show the radius of the circle.

I now need to convert the radius to kilometers.

For example 0.001788057579325097 (How many kilometers is this)

How do I change this to kilometers? I think its just the decimals that is the problem.

```
      // The Drag function is now made and called
         // Add Drag
     drag = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(polygonLayer, {
     autoActivate: true,
     onComplete: displayRadius
     });


 function displayRadius(circle) {
     var area = circle.geometry.getArea();
     var radius = 0.565352 * Math.sqrt(area);
     alert(radius);
      }
```

Comment: What projection do you use?

Comment: @drnextgis EPSG:4326  for my one map and CRS:84 for my other map

Comment: Can you show some code? I'll tell you what that number that is if you show me the code that is producing it.

Comment: @CaptDragon // The Drag function is now made and called
    // Add Drag
         drag = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(polygonLayer, {
         autoActivate: true,
         onComplete: displayRadius
         });

       
     function displayRadius(circle) {
  var area = circle.geometry.getArea();
  var radius = 0.565352 * Math.sqrt(area);
  alert(radius);
}

Comment: @BlakeLoizides : I lied... i can't tell you what that number is. I would guess that it's km. I would draw something around your house or an area you know well, then compare the results to see what it is.

Comment: A figure consisting of points at a constant number of *degrees* from a center is *not* a circle!  The length of a decimal degree changes with direction (and is usually noticeably longer in the north-south direction than in the east-west direction).  A value like 0.001788... decimal degrees will range from 200 meters down to 200 * cos(latitude) meters.  The solution is to use an appropriate projected coordinate system for drawing the circle so that your user gets close to a true circle rather than a (grievously) distorted one.

Comment: I'm a chronic liar.  getArea() will return whatever [map units](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.units) you have chosen. In my case it's meters because i have [meters as my map units](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.units) which i have specified in my [constructor](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.OpenLayers.Map) like this:  `...maxResolution: 156543,
    units: 'm',
    projection: "EPSG:41001"...`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a path geometry from center to some point of your cercle and get the distance of the path (similar to what measure control does).